# how to create new maven dependency plugin for maven project

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, intellij-idea, sbt

I had created a maven project using java . 
Now i want to create a maven dependency so that any other can use this dependency in his own sbt project and will be able to access functions of my maven project .

e.g.  As we do , if we want to use akka in our sbt project , then we simply write the mvn dependency plugin(  **"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.8"**) for akka in my sbt project . and we can access all those class and functions provided by akka .

Simillarly i want to create some plugins for my maven project   .

Please guide me how should i start ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have compiled and tested your libraries you need to install `mvn install` it to repository, it can be your company hosted shared repository and any public repository. You should be able [configure this repository settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) in your pom.xml or settings.xml file.

Once you installed your artifact in a particular repository, your co-worker or any other can access them in java or scala, as long as they have the access to this repository. Typically they will have to specify your repository in there pom xml.

Comment: Tahnks for guiding ... it helped me